# A Riddle From Samuel, My Grandfather's Other Son

Tags: riddle, rhyme, knowledge

> I look toward the eagle, thorn, and snake
>   And find I may someone from danger take
>
> When facing Atlas' rough and salty brine,
>   Beyond the wall is where I now incline
>
> The cellulose destroyers next I see.
>   I split a house of worship centrally.
>
> At last I view the place of peace and rest.
>   A gesture of farewell describes me best.
>
> A greeting in a land that's ceased to be:
>   That suits my circumstances pointlessly.

Solve the riddle by making sense of these ramblings.

Comment: I'm assuming there should be an apostrophe after "Grandfather"; if I'm wrong and this is some kind of very subtle hint, please roll back my edit.

Comment: @Randal'Thor It was, indeed, a mistake.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I think you are

> the United States of America, looking at its borders.

Title:

> my grandfather's other son would be my uncle, so we're looking at **Uncle Sam**.

*I look toward the eagle, thorn, and snake

    And find I may someone from danger take*

> Eagle, thorn, and snake describes the [coat of arms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coat_of_arms_of_Mexico) of **Mexico**, which is **S**outh of the US. To take someone from danger is to **S**AVE them.

*When facing Atlas' rough and salty brine,

    Beyond the wall is where I now incline*

> The first line clearly refers to the **Atlantic Ocean**, which is **E**ast of the US. Inclining beyond the wall, one might find an **E**AVE.

*The cellulose destroyers next I see.

    I split a house of worship centrally.*

> Cellulose destroyers could refer to beavers, found in **Canada** (thanks @GarethMcCaughan), which is **N**orth of the US. Splitting the centre of a church is a **N**AVE.

*At last I view the place of peace and rest.

    A gesture of farewell describes me best.*

> The **Pacific Ocean** sounds like a pacific place, a place of peace, which is **W**est of the US. A gesture of farewell is a **W**AVE.

*A greeting in a land that's ceased to be:

    That suits my circumstances pointlessly.*

> AVE is a greeting in the dead language of Latin, and this is the (compass-)"pointless" version of the words SAVE, EAVE, NAVE, WAVE.

Comment: I think the cellulose destroyers might be beavers.

Comment: @Gareth Beavers *again*? ;-)

Comment: Yeah, it seems we're having a plague of them at the moment.

Comment: Perhaps the central split in the ho**u**se of wor**s**hip is on US?

Comment: @MOehm Interesting idea, thanks. I'm not fully convinced, since that verse should be for Canada, but have edited with your suggestion.

Comment: But I am the US, and I just see the beavers when looking north. But you are right when considering the thematical grouping of the stanzas.

Comment: You have gone in some good directions and are most of the way to the solution.

Comment: Oh, oh! My explanation about the central split was nonsense. The last lines describe the directions, followed by a common greeting in a land that ceased to be: Save, Eave, Nave, Wave.

Comment: Could the wall perhaps be a reference to a seawall, after which the ocean floor often inclines as you head out to sea?

Comment: Ave @MOehm, gratia plena, enigma est tecum.

Comment: Congrats to Rand and @MOehm. Incorporate his latest contribution for the tick.

Comment: @MOehm Wow, that's amazing. Editing now ...

Comment: @HughMeyers And done. Amazing riddle!

Comment: Yes, good puzzle. Nice, how everything slowly unravels.